# Split a text file into multiple text files based on a certain criteria

Tags: python

The text file comes in this format:

```
abcd@gmail.com | Country: US defgh@gmail.com | Country: CA
```

I want to be able to split them into multiple files based on their countries, like US.txt and CA.txt

Comment: Provide a sample input and desired output please. Also provide what you have tried.

Comment: you should try to write some code then we can help you, we can't do the job for you, God help those who help themselves

Answer (score 1):

I'm noticing that the pattern you have above seems to be a single-line file in the pattern of:

`_email_ | Country: _NNN_`

This can be a bit tricky to parse because what seems like a delineater really is not. One bit of steering direction I'll offer is this:

- Read the whole line first
- `split()` with `' '`; You will wind up with a list with a pattern of `[email, '|', 'Country:' NNN]` that repeats over and over again.
- Take each sub-pattern and look at the fourth element (lets call this `natStr`)
- Open a file for appending named `natstr + '.txt'` and write that sub-pattern (recombining it)

I purposefully did not include an actual Python implementation because you should take a look at the `split()` string function and understand file I/O in Python.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I just started learning Python a few days ago

Comment: No problem! I hope you become quite successful with it!

Comment: It looks like I might have to create a for look for this to get everything in the list, am I right?

Comment: You took my hint about "take each sub pattern" correctly; a for-loop will be most useful. After you get that working, you might want to see about creating a generator function instead. And be sure to post your attempt to this question too for better assistance!